# angular is not defined error when karma test invoked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm sure this has something to do with angular-mock.js but I cant figure what I need to do as everything seems to be fine. I'm just going by the default setup from angular-seed app.
Please help get rid of the problem

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config){
  config.set({

    basePath : '../',

    files : [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/js/**/*.js',
      'test/unit/**/*.js'
    ],

    autoWatch : true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['Chrome'],

    plugins : [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine'
            ],

    junitReporter : {
      outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
      suite: 'unit'
    }

  });
};
```

**controllers.js**

```
'use strict';
/* Controllers */

var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
app.constant('RESTURL', 'http://'+ location.hostname + ':8003');

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', 'flash', 'mySharedService','facetSearchService', 'facetSelectionService', 'RESTURL',  function($scope, dataService, flash, sharedService, facetSearch, facet, RESTURL) {
      $scope.RESTURL =  RESTURL;
      $scope.loading = true;
      $scope.data = null;
      $scope.resultCount = 0;
      $scope.currentPage = 0;
      $scope.pageSize = 10;

          ....
])}
```

**controllerSpec.js**

```
'use strict';

/* jasmine specs for controllers go here */

describe('controllers', function(){
  beforeEach(module('myApp.controllers'));


  it('should test MainCtrl', inject(function($controller) {
    //spec body
    var scope = {},
    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {$scope:scope});

    expect($scope.RESTURL).toBe('http://'+ location.hostname + ':8003'));
  }));


});
```

Project file structure:
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I trust you ran "bower install" to install the dependencies?

The paths to bower_components are incorrect. A basepath of "../" will make karma look in the root of your project but your bower_components are in your "app" folder. The "files" in karma.conf need to be prefixed with "app".

Comment: yes i have installed all dependencies & i see the file `angular-mocks.js` as well

Comment: It could be your basePath. Unless you have changed some folders around it should be left empty.

Comment: I have not made any changes to the project structure as its my first angular project I did not want to make silly changes that I'm not familiar with

Comment: Yes indeed. That was the problem. Sorry for getting back so late. Thank you jdewit!